# What is the Best way to manage state in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am a ASP.Net developer and trying to learn AngularJS. There are several ways to manage state in asp.net such as Session, ViewState, Cookies etc.

Can someone explain me or direct me to a good example which is showing state management best practices in angularJs.

For example once user log in to the application I want to store the current user object in client side.

Comment: This is a very good Full Stack where you can start https://github.com/meanjs/mean

Answer (score 7):

**There are many ways to maintain states. You can maintain a state, either using "$scope", or "$rootScope" in AngularJS.**

For example :-

```
angular.module('SampleApp')
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', ExampleCtrl])
  function ExampleCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {

     // for set data
     $scope.data="Hello";
     $rootScope.Globaldata="Hello World";
  }
```

In above example, "$scope" is used for page level or local variable and "$rootScope" is used for maintaining the state globally.

You can access the value of "$rootScope" anywhere in your application, whereas you don't use the value of "$scope".

Another way to store or to maintain data, is using LocalStorage:-

**You can store your value using "angular-local-storage" and "ngCookies".
Follow Below Link :-**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Answer (score 2):

You can use `angular-local-storage`, `ngCookies` to save states and provide persistence. Additionally you can use IndexedDB storage in newer browsers to provide persistence, with the condition that its not available in all the browsers.

A better strategy is to use combination of IndexedDB, localStorage, ngCookies with a fallback to `in-memory` storage. In order to do this you need to have a consistent api/ service which provides this functionality and handles the fallback gracefully within the service itself so that the consumer of the service doesn't need to bother about the fallback mechanism

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-store

This can help you manage your application state much simpler as it will force you to have a one way data flow on your application.

Answer (score 1):

## Ng-Cookies

You could add the Angular service `ng-cookies` this lets you store and retrieve cookies when you inject it into you module. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) is a link to the docs.

#### Add new service

To add a new service to you angular app you will first need to download the js files and add them too you index.html like (from CDN)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=""//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-cookies.js""></script>
```

#### Load into app

In any module you want to use ng-cookies inject like this

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
```

#### Conclusion

Your app now has access to the read and write cookie methods that come with `ng-cookies` But remember that the `CookieStore` service is depreciated so only use ng-cookie

**from Angular Docs**

> Note: The $cookieStore service is deprecated. Please use the $cookies service instead.

Beyond this the Docs are pretty good. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways in which this could be done. I use sample codes based on https://github.com/alarv/ng-login in my applications. I'm using tokens to authenticate the requests.

The sample code demonstrates

1. saving user information in a service called "Session".

2.statechangeEvents to handle authentication with roles.

3. interceptors to handle authentication/ authorization errors in http
   requests.

If you are securing the html resources also, you might need to redirect the page to login page from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

That highly depends on what kind of authentication mechanism you are using on back end.I use token based and session less systems for my projects so I use browsers local storage for storage of authentication tokens but if you are using sessions you will need to use cookies.

If you use local storage make sure you use JSON.stringify() first when saving and on retrieval of that Object make sure you use JSON.parse()

**Disadvantage of localstorage** : only html5 supported

So if your website needs to give support to older browsers you will need to have a fallback on cookies.